# iOS - Control over "${App} wants to open ${Another App}" dialog

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, I have functionality where the user could open another app lets call it as 'App2'. If App2 is not present on the device, then user will be present with an app not available alert that I created, lets call this as Alert1.

However if App2 is present on the device and user tries to open it, Apple's "${App} wants to open App2" dialog is presented. If user clicks 'Cancel' on this, the callback executes my code to present Alert1.

I don't want my app to display Alert1 when user clicks 'Cancel' on Apple's dialog. Is there a way to control Apple's dialog?

***Below is my code:***

```
        if let url = urlComponents.url {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, completionHandler: { success in
                if !success {
                    showAppNotAvailableAlert(url.absoluteString, actionLabel: action.label)
                }
            })
            return
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
        if let url = urlComponents.url {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, completionHandler: { didURLOpen in
                    if !didURLOpen {
                        debugPrint("User pressed cancel button")
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                showAppNotAvailableAlert(url.absoluteString, actionLabel: action.label)
            }
            return
        }
```

idea is to check if app exists by using `canOpenURL`, if it exists then try to open the app and handle error in completion block

Comment: and you don't need return here at all :)

Comment: I was messed with some other methods, sorry. you  answer is good. Here is one small improve - change "success" to something like "urlWasOpened" - it will be more readable and clear.